# How to put comma seperater for a query which has repeated result output?

Tags: mysql

I have an sql query which is giving me some result,i have two columns one is **outlet** and other one is  **PENDINGINDENTNOS**, so in my outlet i have one outlet coming more then one because it  has different PENDINGINDENTNOS

for less confusion see my query

```
select distinct(reorderno) as PENDINGINDENTNOS,outlet from syncolindentfromreorder;
```

It is giving me result like

[image: this is my result]

what i want is WF should come only once and there values 2 and 3 should come as **2,3** and these all outlets are comming from db now in my record i have **WF** Two times it can me thrice or four times for any outlets.

I want this result from query end only because i am populating table (HTML TABLE) with the help of JSP.

SO any one have any idea please Help me out.

Comment: select group_concat(reorderno) as PENDINGINDENTNOS,outlet from syncolindentfromreorder group by outlet;

Comment: there is already an answer @VishwPatel posted 2 mins ago before your comments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using `group_concat()`

```
select outlet,group_concat(distinct reorderno ORDER BY  reorderno ASC SEPARATOR ',') as PENDINGINDENTNOS 
from syncolindentfromreorder
group by outlet
```

OUTPUT:

```
name    PENDINGINDENTNOS
Afcs    1
DF      2
WK      2,3
```

Comment: its giving some diff result, like very different

Comment: should i edit my question with the image of your query result?

Comment: @dheerajkumar, you can

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183530/discussion-between-dheeraj-kumar-and-fa06).

Comment: @dheerajkumar add `order by reorderno` to `group_concat(..)`